What is the difference between @google-cloud/vertexai and @google-cloud/aiplatform?
The npm packages @google-cloud/vertexai and @google-cloud/aiplatform both seem to be maintained. What is the difference between the two?

Vertex AI in the next gen AI Platform. Both are currently actively supported, though users are suggested to prefer (and migrate to if necessary) Vertex AI.
See Vertex AI for AI Platform users for a comparison between them.

Gemini suggests to use the AI Platform in a lot of the code suggestions. Thanks for the link.
